# React Map Method within Map Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am trying to include map method in a map method while getting a list as an element from the first map method.

```
      {columns &&
        columns.map(column => 
        column.list && column.list?
        (column.list.map((item)=>{
        return (
        <CustomTableCell align="center">{item.name}
        <span>{item.convertMethod(item.id, item.lists)}</span>
        </CustomTableCell>
         );
         })):            
        <CustomTableCell align="center"> {column.name} </CustomTableCell>                                        
           ) }
```

[Error still exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejb4U.jpg)

Comment: you are not returning anything in the outer map

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
<div className="App"> 
{
  columns.map(column => {
    return (
      column.list && column.list.length > 0 ? (
        column.list.map(item => {
          return (
            <div key={item.name}>{item.name}</div>
          )
        })
  ): ("")
    )
  })
}
</div>
);
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lamarr-b30j1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. It really helped me as I was sending the data in an object rather in an array